# SQL and perl time formatting

Tags: mysql, perl, datetime

I cant seem to figure out a way to format a string in perl to use in a MySQL DateTime() field.

```
 my $time = "Sat Jun 29 11:20:28 2013 -0400"
```

and i need to format time so it can be entered into a MySQL DateTime() field

```
   Format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

i plan to enter this using perl mysql module

```
   $createQuery = "INSERT INTO something (dated) Values(?) ";
   $sqlQuery = $dbh->prepare($createQuery);
   $sqlQuery->execute($time);
```

Comment: Perhaps one of these [links](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5DTime%3A%3APiece+strptime) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do any formatting yourself.

```
$time = time;
$createQuery = "INSERT INTO something (dated) Values( FROM_UNIXTIME( ? )) ";
$sqlQuery = $dbh->prepare($createQuery);
$sqlQuery->execute($time);
```

If you do really need a string and your data source is not a unix timestamp, just use any of the [formats that MySQL understands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

```
$time = '2013-06-29 18:50:00';
$createQuery = "INSERT INTO something (dated) Values( FROM_UNIXTIME( ? )) ";
$sqlQuery = $dbh->prepare($createQuery);
$sqlQuery->execute($time);
```

Comment: thank you, this worked. I just wrote a function to format it properly, and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use the core module [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) which has been part of the Perl core since 5.9 : [corelist](http://perlpunks.de/corelist/) .

```
use Time::Piece;
my $time = q(Sat Jun 29 11:20:39 2013 -0400);
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($time, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z');
print $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have perl 5.9, [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3A%3AManip) will sort you:

```
$date_as_mysql_likes = UnixDate(ParseDate($your_date_here), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```